# Single-word contractions

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, contractions, conjunction-reduction

How could I describe the following two categories of **single-word** contractions in the least words possible?

A) those that cannot be pronounced the way they are written, and therefore are used only in writing; they start and end with the same letters as the original word and have no apostrophes.
*e.g. Blvd (= Boulevard), bday (= birthday), govt (= government), wknd (= weekend)*

B) those that are considered non-standard in writing, because they are written the way they are pronounced, and therefore are not real words but just pronunciation spellings; there can sometimes be apostrophes here.
*e.g. spose/'spose (= suppose), li'l (= little) / awright/a'right (= alright), nuff (= enough)*

So, these categories are just 2 of a number of lists I've made with all the types of shortened words in English (i.e. contractions / abbreviations / clippings / initialisms / reductions/ eye dialect / etc) for my personal notes, and I just want to add titles to them. For B) I've found "colloquial/spoken (single-word) contractions" and "reductions", which work fine I think. So, since B) are contractions of the spoken form of a word, for A) I think I need to find a title to describe ''contractions of the written form of a word''.
So some of my guesses are:

1. ''Written? single-word contractions'' (not sure if it conveys the exact meaning)
2. ''Single-word contractions used only in writing'' (sounds good but a bit long)
3. ''Contractions of written words'' (not sure)
4. ''Contractions of the written form of a word'' (again a bit long, but conveys the meaning)
5. "Standard single-word contractions" (I think that contrasts best with the "colloquial single-word contractions", which are considered non-standard in writing)

Comment: I understand a contraction to be one word squeezed in from two or more, **don't** you? Your samples are abbreviations.

Comment: No, there are no grammatical terms for such words, since grammar has nothing to do with how words are spelled in writing, only with how words are used in speech.

Comment: According to my sources "Abbreviations and contractions of words both serve to shorten a word, but while abbreviations omit the last few letters of the word, contractions omit letters in the middle of the word." So, accorting to that, 'prof. (= professor)' would be an abbreviation, but 'Dr (= doctor)' would be a contraction.

Comment: I don't understand why you say that *gd* "cannot be pronounced the way [it is] written" but that *sh'd* "can be pronounced the way [it is] written". Surely the apostrophe makes no difference.

Comment: MarcInManhattan You're right, 'gd' should be in the B) list.

Comment: *Febyuary* is hardly a contraction of *February,* and *s'pose* does usually have an apostrophe because letters are omitted. But Prof Lawler has already given you the answer (albeit in a comment), "There are no grammatical terms" for this, since it is not a matter of grammar. Your question might be better if the word *grammatical* were omitted.

Comment: Andrew Leach Thanks, I changed that. Actually, that's why I rephrased my question in the comments to explain more clearly what I'm looking for. What would you say "Febyuary" is? Maybe "eye dialect"?

Comment: @YosefBaskin No. "O'er" is a contraction.

Comment: I like this one.  forecastle -> fo'c'sle

Comment: @GEdgar fo'c's'le's better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  fo'c's'le is not in my dictionary.

Comment: @GEdgar You only have the one?